# Disambiguation of Names using Edit Distance

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I have a huge list of company names and a huge list of zipcodes associated with those names. (>100,000).

I have to output similar names (for example, AJAX INC and AJAX are the same company, I have chosen a threshold of 4 characters for edit distance), but only if their corresponding zipcodes match too.

The trouble is that I can put all these company names in a dictionary, and associate a list of zipcode and other characteristics with that dictionary key. However, then I have to match each pair, and with O(n^2), it takes forever. Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary keyed by zipcode, with lists of company names as the values. Now you only have to match company names *per zipcode*, a much smaller search space.

Comment: You have no idea how stupid I feel for not thinking of that. Thanks.